# Remove spaces using javascript

Tags: javascript

How to remove all spaces from string using javascript.
    I have a code like this--

```
var Title = "";
var Str="g g";
Title = Str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
this gives me result Title=g g
how to get result Title=gg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following regexp:

```
Str.replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

The one you have right now just strippes spaces from start or end of your string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Title = Str.replace(/ /g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change code to:

```
var title = Str.replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

Your original regular expression would trim spaces only from the beginning or the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use:

```
var Str="g g";
Str.replace(" ", "");
```